# How to rewrite the URL in Nginx Regex and debug?

Tags: regex, nginx, wsgi

I am trying to remove /api/v1 from the request URL and simply pass the rest of the part. For example /api/v1/test/ as simply /test. /api/v1/test/ready as simply /test/ready.

Here is what I have tried. I am thinking the first parameter i.e. $1 will be captured in ^(/api/v1) and the rest of the part will be captured (.*?).
So, I am simply passing  $2 and breaking it. However, it is not working. I am unsure what am I doing wrong. I tried some debugging but failed to do so.

```
location /api/v1 {
      rewrite ^(/api/v1)(.*?) $2; break;
      # tried return 200 $2;
      # but this will never hit since it is rewriting 
      # the rules will be evaluated again.
      # I guess break will not allow it to re run again for the rules.
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass 10.0.2.15:3031;
    }
```

I was trying to debug it but I couldn't.
It never hit the location /. For example.

```
location / {
             return 200 $request_uri;
      }
```

Comment: The rest of the string cannot be matched with a lazy pattern, replace `(.*?)` with `(.*)`

Comment: Also, you have a spurious `;` between the `$2` and the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could spot the problem. Here is my solution.
I think the obvious way to figure out what was going wrong was after enabling the redirection logs -

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
 rewrite_log on;
```

Here is the location context.

```
location /api/v1 {

            # uncomment the below two lines to see the redirection.
            # the re-direction happens from  /api/v1/ to /
            # error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
            # rewrite_log on;
            rewrite ^(/api/v1)(.*)/$ https://$host$2 break;
            
        }

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/sb_web_wsgi.sock;
            include uwsgi_params;
        }
```